# How to setup dbms_job with out parameter

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I'm trying to run some procedures in parallel using dbms_jobs but i'm having some issues doing it. When trying to run below code, i'm getting this error

```
20:28:16 Info: Job #16 could not be executed. ORA-12011: execution of 1 jobs failed 
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_IJOB", line 469 
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_JOB", line 282 
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

---

```
declare 
  ln_dummy number; 
  p_stdate CONSTANT DATE := '01-MAY-2012'; 
  p_edate  CONSTANT DATE := '31-MAY-2012'; 
  p_cdate CONSTANT DATE := '09-FEB-2013'; 
  p_key CONSTANT INTEGER:= 0; 
  p_ercode  INTEGER; 
  p_erdesc  VARCHAR2(200); 
begin 
  COMMIT; 
  DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(ln_dummy,'MY_PROC_1('''|| p_stdate ||''','''|| p_edate ||''','''|| p_cdate||''','''|| p_key ||''', :p_ercode, :p_erdesc: );'); 
  COMMIT; 
end; 
/
```

p_ercode and p_erdesc is an out parameter in MY_PROC_1. If I try to comment it out the job runs without an issue.

My question is how can I run the job without commenting out p_ercode and p_erdesc in MY_PROC_1.

Also, is there a way to know which job is running and which job is already done?  Something like an alert?

Comment: Where would those out parameters be returned to? The proc. that calls submit_job will be long gone when the job actually runs.

Comment: Hi mat thanks for your reply. I'm kinda new with plsql. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Please explain what you'd want to do with those out parameters if you could use them. Once you do that, you should be able to figure out what to do yourself.

Comment: both parameters are for when MY_PROC_1 generates an error upon executing. It would assign the error code and error description in those variables and insert them into a log table.

Comment: Well, that logging to a log table isn't going to happen by magic, right? So what can you do about it?

Comment: actually i can do nothing about it. All of the procedures i'm going to schedule have the out parameters. I just can't modify them all. I'm thinking there is a proper way of scheduling procedures that has out parameters.

Comment: Write a procedure that wraps the ones you want to run and does the logging.

Comment: hi mat. can you provide me an example? sorry im quite confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe, this will work?

```
declare 
  ln_dummy number; 
  p_stdate CONSTANT DATE := '01-MAY-2012'; 
  p_edate  CONSTANT DATE := '31-MAY-2012'; 
  p_cdate CONSTANT DATE := '09-FEB-2013'; 
  p_key CONSTANT INTEGER:= 0; 
begin 
  COMMIT; 
  DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(ln_dummy,'
    declare 
      p_ercode  INTEGER; 
      p_erdesc  VARCHAR2(200); 
    begin
      MY_PROC_1('''|| p_stdate ||''','''|| p_edate ||''','''|| p_cdate||''','''|| p_key ||''', p_ercode, p_erdesc );
    end;
  '); 
  COMMIT; 
end;
```

Comment: awesome! didn't know this is possible. Thank you very much. This one did the job for me! :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to log the outputs you can create a table:

```
SQL> create table log_table
  2  (
  3    job_id     number,
  4    start_time date,
  5    end_time   date,
  6    retcode    number,
  7    retstr     varchar2(4000)
  8  )
  9  /

Table created.
```

then execute the job. i've made a wrapper procedure just to make it a bit neater but you could put all of this in the job if you wanted.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure my_proc_1_job(
  2    p_job    number,
  3    p_stdate date,
  4    p_edate  date,
  5    p_cdate  date,
  6    p_key    integer)
  7  is
  8    v_errcode integer;
  9    v_errdesc varchar2(32767);
 10    v_start_date date;
 11  begin
 12    v_start_date := sysdate;
 13    my_proc_1(p_stdate, p_edate, p_cdate, p_key, v_errcode, v_errdesc);
 14    insert into log_table (job_id, start_time, end_time, retcode, retstr)
 15    values (p_job, v_start_date, sysdate, v_errcode, v_errdesc);
 16    commit;
 17  end;
 18  /

Procedure created.

SQL> declare
  2    ln_dummy number;
  3    p_stdate CONSTANT varchar2(20) := '01-MAY-2012';
  4    p_edate  CONSTANT varchar2(20) := '31-MAY-2012';
  5    p_cdate CONSTANT varchar2(20) := '09-FEB-2013';
  6    p_key CONSTANT INTEGER:= 0;
  7  begin
  8    COMMIT;
  9    DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(
 10      ln_dummy,
 11       'my_proc_1_job(
 12           JOB, to_date('''|| p_stdate ||''',''DD-MON-YYYY''),
 13           to_date('''|| p_edate ||''',''DD-MON-YYYY''),
 14           to_date('''|| p_cdate ||''',''DD-MON-YYYY''),
 15           ' || p_key || ');');
 16    COMMIT;
 17  end;
 18  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from log_table;

    JOB_ID START_TIM END_TIME     RETCODE
---------- --------- --------- ----------
RETSTR
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         4 10-FEB-13 10-FEB-13         -1
failure
```

now all runs are recorded in `LOG_TABLE`.

Comment: thank you very much for this. definitely going to try it out. For now, Egor's answer did the job for me.